# How could I stop these arrays from generating further numbers when one of the two have finished?

Tags: ruby

In the following program..

```
def random_number
  if rand(2) == 1
    rand(1..25)
  else
    0
  end
end

def random_array
  array = [99]
  array << (array.last - random_number) while array.last > 0
  puts array.inspect
  array
end

array_1 = random_array
array_2 = random_array
```

These 2 arrays will generate numbers until the last number in both arrays are 0 or less.  What i'm trying to figure out is how to stop one array from generating further numbers when the other array has completed the task.

For example, if array_1 ends with the last number being 0 or less, then array_2 will stop generating numbers even though its last number hasn't reached 0 yet.

Comment: array_1 will ends always before array_2, because you aren't working with Thread

Comment: Even if you put it into threads, the first array will fill up before the second thread gets created.

Comment: Do you care if both arrays end up with same length or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update both arrays until one of them goes below zero:

```
def random_number
  if rand(2) == 1
    rand(1..25)
  else
    0
  end
end

array_1 = [99]
array_2 = [99]

loop do
  break if array_2.last.negative?
  array_1 << array_1.last - random_number
  break if array_1.last.negative?
  array_2 << array_2.last - random_number
end

puts "Array 1 (#{array_1.size} items)"
puts array_1.inspect
puts "Array 2 (#{array_2.size} items)"
puts array_2.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure but I guess this could be a solution

```rb
def random_arrays
  array_1 = [99]
  array_2 = [99]
  while array_1.last > 0 && array_2.last > 0
    array_1 << (array_1.last - random_number)
    array_2 << (array_2.last - random_number)
  end
  puts array_1.inspect
  puts array_2.inspect
  return array_1, array_2
end

array_1, array_2 = random_arrays
```